# Saving Edits on a WFS using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3, geoserver

So with an app that I've produced by taking [this](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-5/) into account, I've managed to create a web map with editing function.

Problem is that, unlike in [the working example](http://dbauszus-webmaps.appspot.com/ol3-wfs-t),  the edits are not being saved properly, so every time the page gets refreshed, it seems that the edits become lost.

Weird thing is that every time I draw a line, in my database there are new entries being created, but the geometry isn't being recorded.

The portion that saves it to the WFS layer is:

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
featureNS: 'http://geoserver.org/bftchamber',
featureType: 'bft',
srsName: 'EPSG:27700'
});
var transactWFS = function(p,f) {
switch(p) {
case 'insert':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
    break;
case 'update':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
    break;
case 'delete':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
    break;
}
s = new XMLSerializer();
str = s.serializeToString(node);
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: str
    }).done();
}
```

Fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/Luffydude/ex06jr1e/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem lied in the fact that my geometry column needed to be called geometry and OpenLayers only works with with EPSG:3857.

The code is correct